# Why doesn't this recursion produce a StackOverFlowException?

Tags: c#, .net, recursion, stack-overflow, csc

What is wrong with this code:

```
using System;
namespace app1
{
    static class Program
    {
        static int x = 0;
        static void Main()
        {
            fn1();
        }
        static void fn1()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(x++);
            fn1();
        }
    }
}
```

I compile this piece of code using this command:

```
csc /warn:0 /out:app4noex.exe app4.cs
```

When I double click on the exe, it doesn't seem to throw the exception (StackOverFlowException), and keep running forever.

Using visual studio command prompt 2010, but I also have vs 2012 installed on the system, all up to date.

Comment: check out "tail recursion"

Comment: Perhaps it will if you remove the logging output (which takes ages)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight do you think the compiler is _this_ smart?

Comment: You might not run out of space on the stack but when you get to int.MaxValue and try and increment it, you'll get an exception.

Comment: @TrevorPilley C# doesn't just overflow?

Comment: @JanDvorak no, you'll get an exception. You can override this behavior via the unchecked keyword though: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a569z7k8(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: @BlackBear I think the ability to disable this check shifts C# from WTFy back to awesome :-)

Comment: LINQPad blows up on this code.

Comment: Tail recursive calls (like this one) are optimized away in the x64 jitter but not in x86.

Comment: @JanDvorak, no, it will throw an `OverflowException` when `x = int.MaxValue` and you call `x++` but as BlackBear states, you can disable this default behaviour by specifying `unchecked`.

Comment: @JanDvorak see this excellent post for details: http://community.bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2010/07/07/the-case-of-the-failed-demo-stackoverflowexception-on-x64.aspx

Comment: @JanDvorak Why, eliminating tail call is pretty standard and straightforward. It has been around for ages, and it works very well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because the optimizer unrolls the tail recursion call into:

```
    static void fn1()
    {
      START:

        Console.WriteLine(x++);
        GOTO START;
    }
```

Rewrite to get exceptions like so:

```
   static int y;

   static void fn1()
   {
       Console.WriteLine(x++);
       fn1();
       Console.WriteLine(y++);
   }
```

Comment: Verified by the author who does not get the exception. But tail recursion is a well-known optimization, now does CLR jitter do it? according to the querent it does.

Comment: It would be worthwhile to dismiss the other alternatives first before jumping to conclusions.

Comment: I think the behaviour is processor dependent. IIRC, this won't get turned into a tail call on x86

Comment: I spoke too soon... http://blogs.msdn.com/b/clrcodegeneration/archive/2009/05/11/tail-call-improvements-in-net-framework-4.aspx Looks like things have changed since I ran into this.

Answer (score 3):

The x64 jitter is detecting this as a tail call and optimizing it away while the x86 jitter does not do this. The x64 jitter is more aggressive about these optmizations. See Bart de Smet's [analysis](http://community.bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2010/07/07/the-case-of-the-failed-demo-stackoverflowexception-on-x64.aspx) and the CLR team's [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/clrcodegeneration/archive/2009/05/11/tail-call-improvements-in-net-framework-4.aspx) on it.

Answer (score 1):

There is such a thing called [tail recursive optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call).

From a stack perspective, basically it means that if the last thing an method does is call another method, the new call can take the stack frame of the calling method. For example in:

```
static void Main()
{
  fn(0);
}

static void fn(int value)
{
   fn(value+1);
}
```

instead of the call stack growing `Main->fn(0)->fn(1)->...` ad nauseam, it will be at exactly two links long, first `Main->fn(0)` than `Main->fn(1)`, up to `Main->fn(int.MaxValue)` where it will either blow up or overflow.

Now, the question is, does the C# compiler actually does this?
AFAIK, using the 4.0 and later C# compilers, when compiling in a x86 environment, it **does not** use tail-call optimization, and when compiling x64 application, it **does** use tail-call optimization (and apparently, from the other comments/answers I'm correct). E.g. On my system, using LINQPad, the code you provided promptly blew up with a `StackOverflowException`.

Answer (score -1):

When program runs in visual studio environment , it will uses a limited stack deep. I mean that when you compile a program in VS2012 by hitting F5 and F6 on keyboard, it will send some parameters to csc.exe program to limit the program and cause the stack-over-flow to aware you of bug that is into your program source code &  algorithm.
In reality , there is no Stack-over-flow error, program's process will use real storage and virtual storage and OS will done it for you.

Note : it is also related to your os , some os will throw an error if they are weakness on memory management and cpu scheduling .